# How to refresh a div content when clicking a link without reloading all the page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

In my website authors (users) can mark posts as favorite.

It works this way:

```
   if ($favinfo == NULL || $favinfo == "") { 
      $favicon = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/author/favorites.php?add=".$articleinfo['id']."\">ADD</a>"; .
   }
    else { 
      $favicon = "<a href=\"".$siteurl."/author/favorites.php?remove=".$articleinfo['id']."\">REMOVE</a>"; 
   }
```

Its suposed to look dynamic, it works, when user click ADD, it adds the post to his favorites and reload the page with the REMOVE link.

The problem is its not really dynamic it reloads all the page.

How can i only reload that link (wich is inside a div)?

I know i have to use ajax, jquery, etc, but i tried some examples found here in S.O. but no success.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery load() [http://api.jquery.com/load/]

Comment: Use ajax to send a request to the server, evaluate the request server-side, respond accordingly, update element with data.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('a').on('click', function(e){

    // the default for a link is to post a page..    
    // So you can stop the propagation

     e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Including this stop you page from reloading your entire page

Comment: Exactly where do i need to include this code? Will it "stop propagation" for  all "a" tags? I need to "stop propagation" only for that link in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be dynamic, you will need to use AJAX. jQuery has [ajax support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which makes this really easy. If you are not familiar with ajax or javascript you should read up on it first.

### PHP

```php
if ($favinfo == NULL || $favinfo == "") { 
    $favicon = "<a class=\"fav-btn\" data-id=\"".$articleinfo['id']."\" data-action=\"add\" href=\"".$siteurl."/author/favorites.php"\">ADD</a>"; .
}
else { 
    $favicon = "<a class=\"fav-btn\" data-id=\"".$articleinfo['id']."\" data-action=\"remove\" href=\"".$siteurl."/author/favorites.php"\">REMOVE</a>"; 
}
```

### JavaScript

> $('a.fav-btn').on('click', function(e){
>
> ```
>   var $this = $(this),                    // equates to the clicked $('a.fav-btn')
>       url = $this.attr('href'),           // get the url to submit via ajax
>       id = $this.attr('data-id'),         // id of post
>       action = $this.attr('data-action'); // action to take on server
>
>
>   $.ajax({
>       url: url+'?'+action+'='+id
>   }).done(function(){ // once favorites.php?[action]= is done...
>
>       // because this is in .done(), the button will update once the server has finished
>       // if you want the link to change instantly and not wait for server, move this outside of the done function
>       if(action === 'add'){
>           $this.attr('data-action', 'remove').html('REMOVE'); // update the button/link
>       }else{
>           $this.attr('data-action', 'add').html('ADD');
>       }
>
>   })
>
>   return false; // prevent link from working so the page doesn't reload
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using JQuery, you have some tools to accomplish this.

1. Have a structure / method of identifying your links.
2. You can have a [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) listener on your add button that will call a JQuery [$.post(url, callback)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function.
3. In that callback function, you can have it update the corresponding DIV (that you defined in #1) with a 'remove' link.  i.e if you identify the DIV by ID, you can retrieve it via [$('#id')](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and then update that object.

The same idea can apply with the 'remove' link that you add.

So, generally...

```
<button id="add">Add</button>

<div id="links"> ...</div>

<script>
$('#add').click(function() { 
     $.post('your url',
         function(data) {
             var links = $('#links');
             // update your links with 'remove' button, etc
         }
     );
});

</script>
```